the ajax request is not giving the expected result
I'm currently working on a project where I'm using AJAX to verify if a user is an admin based on certain criteria. However, I'm encountering an issue with the AJAX response. Here's the relevant code:
handle_user_type
class ADMINS{
    private $email_pattern;
    private $username_pattern;
    private $password_pattern;
    private bool $flag_username_admin=false;
    private bool $flag_password_admin=false;
    private bool $flag_email_admin=false;

    public function set_flag_username($value){
        $this->flag_username_admin=$value;
    }

    public function set_flag_password($value){
        $this->flag_password_admin=$value;
    }

    public function set_flag_email($value){
        $this->flag_email_admin=$value;
    }

    public function get_flag_username()
    {
        return $this->flag_username_admin;
    }

    public function get_flag_password(){
        return $this->flag_password_admin;
    }

    public function get_flag_email(){
        return $this->flag_email_admin;
    }

    public function set_password_pattern(){
        $this->password_pattern = '/^A_[a-zA-Z]+_D_[a-zA-Z]+_M_[a-zA-Z]+_I_[a-zA-Z]+_N_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+$/';
        return $this->password_pattern;
    }

    public function set_username_pattern(){
        $this->username_pattern='/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_ADM+\w+$/';
        return $this->username_pattern;
    }

    public function set_email_pattern(){
        $this->email_pattern='/^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\-]+[ADMN]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/';
        return $this->email_pattern;
    }

    public function check_REGEX(){
    }

}

$user_Admin=new ADMINS();
$user_Admin->check_REGEX();

class Users extends ADMINS{

    private $username;
    private $username_err;
    private $password;
    private $password_err;
    private $confirm_password;
    private $confirm_password_err;
    private $email;
    private $email_err;

    public function get_username(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function get_password(){
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function get_email(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function get_email_err(){
        return $this->email_err;
    }

    public function get_username_err(){
        return $this->username_err;
    }

    public function get_password_err(){
        return $this->password_err;
    }

    public function get_confirm_err(){
        return $this->confirm_password_err;
    }

    public function get_confirm(){
        return $this->confirm_password;
    }

    public function set_username($username){
        $this->username=$username;
    }

    public function set_password($password){
        $this->password=$password;
    }

    public function set_email($email){
        $this->email=$email;
    }

    public function set_email_err($email_err){
        $this->email_err=$email_err;
    }

    public function set_password_err($password_err){
        $this->password_err=$password_err;
    }

    public function set_username_err($username_err){
        $this->username_err=$username_err;
    }

    public function set_confirm_err($confirm_err){
        $this->confirm_password_err=$confirm_err;
    }

    public function set_confirm($confirm){
        $this->confirm_password=$confirm;
    }

    public function formular_inputs_and_data(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
                $this->set_username_err("You should enter the username");
            }
            elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["username"]))){
                $this->set_username_err("Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscore");
            }
            else{
                if(preg_match($this->set_username_pattern(), trim($_POST["username"]))) {
                    $this->set_flag_username(true);
                }
                $this->set_username(trim($_POST["username"]));
                echo $this->get_username()."<br>";
                echo($this->get_flag_username())?"true":"false";
            }

            if(empty(trim($_POST["email"])) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/',$_POST["email"])){
                $this->set_email_err("The email is empty or email does not match the requirements");
            }
            else{
                if(preg_match($this->set_email_pattern(),$_POST["email"])) {
                    $this->set_flag_email(true);
                }
                $this->set_email(trim($_POST["email"]));
                echo  "<br>".$this->get_email()."<br>";
                echo ($this->get_flag_email())?"true":"false";
            }

            if(empty(trim($_POST["password"])) || strlen(trim($_POST["password"])<8)){
                $this->set_password_err("The password is empty or does not match the length");
            } else {
                if(preg_match($this->set_password_pattern(), trim($_POST["password"]))) {
                    $this->set_flag_password(true);
                }
                $this->set_password(trim($_POST["password"]));
                echo "<br>".$this->get_password()."<br>";
                echo ($this->get_flag_password())?"true":"false";
            }

            if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"])) || $_POST["confirm_password"]!=$this->get_password()){
                $this->set_password_err("The passwords does not match");
            }
            if(!empty($this->get_password_err()) && !empty($this->get_confirm_err())){
                $this->set_password("");
                $this->set_confirm("");
            }
        }
    }

    public function check_if_admin(){
        $status = ($this->get_flag_username()) ? "true" : "FALSE";
        // Debugging statement

        // Return the admin status as JSON
        echo json_encode($status);
    }

    }

     $users=new Users();
     $users->formular_inputs_and_data();

   

    // AJAX Response Handling
    if (isset($_GET['function_name'])) {
    $function_name = $_GET['function_name'];

    if (method_exists($users, $function_name)) {
        $users->$function_name();
    } else {
        echo json_encode("Function not found");
    }
}

JavaScript file with the ajax request
get_Data_via_ajax() {
    fetch("../user_authentifications/handle_user_type.php?function_name=check_if_admin")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("Received response:", data); // Log the response
        alert(data);
        // if (data === true || data === "true") {
        //     alert("User is an admin!");
        // } else {
        //     alert("User is not an admin.");
        // }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    });
}

The problem I'm facing is that even when the response from the server is "true", the JavaScript alerts "false". I've checked the server response, and it seems to be correct. Why is the JavaScript alert not displaying the correct value?
I've tried debugging by logging the response to the console, and it shows "false" even though the server response is "true".

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? "the JavaScript alerts "false"" - what does that mean? There's no code given that alerts "false"

Also, running any method on the $users object (without checking whether this is an allowed action) sounds like a possible entry point for hackers

You don't seem to have shown us all the relevant parts of the code. Your URL contains function_name=check_if_admin ...so according to the PHP code that should cause $users->check_if_admin(); to be executed. But you haven't shown us any code for a function called check_if_admin...so we don't know what that does or what it returns, or whether it echoes anything. You showed a function called admin, but not check_if_admin. Make sure you always post a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post - thanks.

P.S. Why are you JSON-encoding simple strings? That seems fairly pointless. While it can work, it's not really worthwhile. The point of JSON is to transmit a more complex data structure, e.g. an array, or an object with multiple properties.

Its is not clear with the snippet, where you have defined "$users" and what actually is logic in function "check_if_admin". plus how "$users" is managed in php code, because it is not passed through JS in the mentioned code.

I thought that would be efficient to take the result from other file using AJAX, because I want to insert dynamically some html elements if the condition met the requirements  @ADyson

I'm not sure which of my remarks that's an answer to, or what it's relevant to in terms of your problem, tbh.

this is a JS problem, like the response from AJAX is false always even the result should be true, I used the "alert" function just for checking if I will got the right answer @Nico Haase

I answered to your second remark @ADyson

even when the response from the server is "true", the JavaScript alerts "false"...that simply isn't possible, you must be mistaken somehow. I've checked the server response...how and where did you do that, precisely?

The fact that you want to insert some HTML elements if the condition is met has no relevance to why you're JSON-encoding simple strings instead of just echoing those strings - the result will be functionally the same.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and remove those parts from your code that are not relevant

Anyway, thanks for providing more code, it's clearer now. So...your code will run $this->set_flag_username(true);, but only if preg_match($this->set_username_pattern(), trim($_POST["username"]) returns true. But since your fetch request does not send a POST request, or any POST data, then that condition will never be true, because $_POST["username"] will not have a value during that request. Therefore check_if_admin will always return false because it relies on flag_username_admin being true, and as I've explained that won't ever happen. So that's why you get a "false" response

I've no idea where/when/how you think you're seeing it return true. Perhaps that's actually the response to a different request to the server (e.g. one where a form was POSTed), but without proper details it's unclear. Either way the code you've posted will return false, which makes sense for the reasons I outlined above.

I tried to use Ajax because I didn't know exactly how I can solve this problem using just php, like I thought that using Ajax will help me to that response and with that to insert HTML elements, not only that but I thought that later I can handle more easly the data.. I'm sorry if I don't know much stuff about this, but I'm still in process of learning, and I'm really confused rn  (This is for the second remark) @ADyson

I'm seeing true if I'm echoing the data inside of my php file that handle the user type or in the file where is created the register @ADyson

Ok so I read your responses, and I understand now, and my question is: Is there any method that will help me to solve this error? or I should rewrite the whole file?  @ADyson

If you can, of course, another idea was to save the result in $_POST['user_type'] and then to take the result using ajax, if I'm wrong maybe you could tell me other way  @ADyson

Looking at the code, your fetch() request would need to send a POST request, and include the "username" value in the data it sends, so that $_POST["username"] will contain a value when the PHP runs.

Ok,today I tried what you said and now it works, thank you for your explanations!!@ADyson

No problem. If you think the code solution would be useful to others who might have a similar situation in their code, then please post it as an Answer below, so it can be searched on, and voted on. See also [answer] - thanks.

Is this your solution? If so please post an Answer in the box below, not a comment :-). P.s. why did you change fetch() for $.ajax? They do exactly the same job

Oh my bad, I'm still learning how this works, I will change it, I know that they do exactly the same job, I thought it was better understood if I'm using $_ajax, I can change it but idk, I could provide the solution with fetch also @ADyson

I'm using fetch() in other files:)

It's up to you if you use fetch() or $.ajax. I was just pointing it out. But please, post an answer, not a comment! Comments cannot be searched, you cannot get points from votes for them, and it looks like your question has no solution. There is a box underneath marked "Answer", that's where you need to put your code. See also [answer]. Take the [tour] if you're not sure how the format works here.
